# Can't use QWERTY layout after make IBus work with Dvorak layout after reboot

Tags: keyboard-layout, reboot, ibus, input-method, dvorak

To keep my Input Method (Bogo or Unikey) of IBus working with Dvorak keyboard layout after reboot, I use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` to set keyboard as Dvorak, and go to tab Advance in IBus Preferences to check Use system keyboard layout.

The problem is, sometimes my friends want to borrow my laptop and I can not easily switch to Qwerty layout because any Input Method will use Dvorak. The English - English (US) is the same as English - English (Dvorak) one.

Any idea? Please help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few keyboard layout related changes were implemented in Ubuntu 13.10. I'm certainly not an expert on the topic, but I think you should at first hand use **System Settings -> Text Entry** to set your preferences rather than using ibus-setup directly.

Comment: I am still not success. Can you help me with another way?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have the knowledge needed to come up with anything else. Hopefully someone else jumps in and gives you a hand.